# QButtonGroup only contains one button if they are added iteratively

Tags: python, qt, button, pyqt

I'm missing something super simple.. but I've spent 15 minutes on it now, and I don't see it.

This code produces a QButtonGroup with 3 buttons:

```
from qtpy.QtWidgets import (
    QButtonGroup,
    QPushButton,
    QRadioButton,
    )

buttons = list()
for label in ("Beginner", "Senior", "Expert"):
    cs = QPushButton()
    cs.setObjectName(f"pushButton_{label}")
    cs.setText(label)
    buttons.append(cs)
    
cs_group = QButtonGroup()
for cs in buttons:
    cs_group.addButton(cs)
```

`cs_group.buttons()` -> list of 3 elements

This one produces a QButtonGroup with a single button:

```
from qtpy.QtWidgets import (
    QButtonGroup,
    QPushButton,
    QRadioButton,
    )

cs_group = QButtonGroup()
for label in ("Beginner", "Senior", "Expert"):
    cs = QPushButton()
    cs.setObjectName(f"pushButton_{label}")
    cs.setText(label)
    cs_group.addButton(cs)
```

`cs_group.buttons()` -> list with a single element.. the last one.

What am I missing !?

Comment: Each button goes out of scope (and therefore destroyed) when the loop restarts unless it has a persistent reference (adding the button to a parent, or to a data structure like a list, as you did in your first example). Add those buttons to a layout of a parent widget and you'll always get them.

Comment: so adding them to a QButtonGroup is not enough to prevent them from being garbage collected..

Comment: Exactly: the button group doesn't take *ownership* of the button (nor it should). It only keeps an *internal* (on the "C++ side") reference to the buttons which is not enough to keep them "alive" (more or less like a weakref): as soon as a button is destroyed, it gets removed from that group as well. In the second example you get only one button because the loop has ended and you still have a reference created by the last iteration.

Comment: Thank you, that's very clear! I was so confused, I was really not expecting the buttons to be garbage collected in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you do not manage the lifetime of your button instances. So, at the end of the scope of their declaration, they get destructed. They will no longer be valid. This is because the default parent is no parent.

You would need to introduce some parent-child relationship that is typical with Qt. I would probably just parent them to the current widget where you are executing this code.

The same applies to your button group.